# printNewEdition does not work after burning an edition

Tags: metaplex, metaplex-js, mpl-token-metadata

I use this code to print.

```
metaplex.nfts().printNewEdition({
        originalMint: new PublicKey(masterEditionMint)
      })
```

Then I use burn_edition_nft instruction to burn the minted one. Both work but after burning when I try printing again, I got this error:

```
  key: 'metaplex.errors.program.parsed_program_error',
  title: 'TokenMetadataProgram > Already initialized',
```

When I check the source code of the metadata program, it seems that a metadata and/or edition account is already created. And when I explore these, they seem closed.

Any idea?

Comment: It seems, printNewEdition function uses current master edition's supply which is actually decreased when burn_edition_nft is run. This cause to a wrong number of edition to be tried to be minted.